# shell_exec(lpr $var) wont print

Tags: php, localhost, shell-exec, lpr

I'm trying to send a codebar to a thermal printer via shell_excec(), the variable 'a' contains the route of the desired code and the code name itself. 
I'm working on localhost.
My problem is that this chunk of code is properly executed in GNU/Linux (Trisquel) but when I switch to OsX it won't work

My first guess was that the file didn't had the proper permissions, but already checked and that's not the problem.

```
<?php
$cod =$_POST["a"];
$salida = shell_exec('lpr '.$cod);
echo $salida.' lpr '.$cod;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add 2>&1 to end of you comand to exec:

```
shell_exec('lpr '.$cod.' 2>&1');
```

It may help tp you get more data from output produced by lpr

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I got this output

    dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
    Referenced from: /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    in /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib

Comment: Looks like as some misconfig in libraries used. I'm not use MacOS to tell more. This may help: https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/issues/detail?id=18   also, may suggest to try to use some other console program to do same what you want

Comment: I've tried it, it won't even let me through the ./configure statement to make && install.